# How to populate to an array using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Below is the full code that I wish to implement. I get a ''Run-time error '6': Overflow when the code is run.

The main objective is to send an email with the values the code returns as a single email.

The output of this code is the last value instead of all the values.

```
Sub Email()

Dim Outlook, OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String, EmailSendTo As String, MailBody As String
Dim SigString As String, Signature As String, fpath As String
Dim Quarter As String, client() As Variant
Dim Alert As Date, Today As Date, Days As Integer, Due As Integer

Set Outlook = OpenOutlook

Quarter = Range("G4").Value
Set rng = Range(Range("G5"), Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'Resize Array prior to loading data
ReDim client(rng.Rows.Count)

'Check column G for blank cells and return F cells
For Each Cell In rng
If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
    ReDim client(x)
    Alert = Cell.Offset(0, 0).Value
    Today = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")
    Days = Alert - Today
    Due = Days * -1
    client(x) = Cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " " & Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
End If
Next
    For x = LBound(client) To UBound(client)
        List = client(x) & vbNewLine
        List = List + List
    Next x
        
'Check dates to send subject line'
    If Days < 0 Then
    mail = True
    EmailSubject = Quarter & " Vat Returns are Overdue"
    MailBody = "<p>The Vat Returns are overdue by " & Due & " Days. See the clients below: </p>" & List
    ElseIf Days <= 14 Then
    mail = True
    EmailSubject = "Vat Returns are due within Two weeks"
    MailBody = "<p>The Vat Returns are due in " & Days & " Days. See the clients below: </p>" & List
    End If
    
   
    
'Fetch signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\.htm"
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    
'Fetch link for file location
    fpath = "K:
    
'Skip if mail=false
    If mail = True Then
    
'Send Mail
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
        With OutMail
            .Subject = EmailSubject
            .To = ""
            '.bcc
            sHTML = "<HTML><BODY>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>Hi, </p>"
            sHTML = sHTML & MailBody
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>If the Vat Return have been filed, please update the database using the link below.</p>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<A href='" & fpath & "'></A>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>Regards,</p>"
            .HTMLBody = sHTML & Signature
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</BODY></HTML>"
            .Display
        End With
        
        Set Outlook = Nothing
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        
        mail = False
        EmailSendTo = ""
        
 End If
End Sub
```

All this code returns is an open window in outlook with no new email displayed.

What I want to achieve is that the code will run though the range of data. If the cell in column G:G is blank then return the cell value in column F:F.

I want the code to store these values to then send an email to an email address. I can code it to send multiple emails to one email address with one cell value in each email. I want it to send one single email to the email address with all (multiple) cell values that is returned.

I have taken out all the personal details in the code but this will not affect the running of the code.

Comment: I don't know that this solves the problem, but it might. Drop the `ARRAY()` function from the `List(x) = Array(Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value)` line. You are wanting to retrieve a value from a cell and add it to the `List` array. It doesn't make sense to wrap the value returned from the cell in `Array()` for this.

Comment: FYI `Dim rng, Cell As Range` declares `rng` as Variant - every variable needs a type, otherwise it's a Variant.

Comment: `.AutoFilter 7, ""` - but the range is only one column?  Suggest you remove `On Error Resume Next` and see whether you get any errors.

Comment: @JNevill that is correct. Another problem has occurred. It only prints the first 2 values but their should be 3 in this case.

Comment: I suspect that @TimWilliams suggestion to drop `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` may be illuminating for that problem. There may be an index-out-of-bound error being thrown as you iterate the blank range and assign values to elements of the array. And that potential error may stem from your `redim`, lack of initialization of your `x` variable (`x=0` before iterating would be appropriate), and the fact that arrays are zero-based. That's a bit of a guess though.

Comment: Can you try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing? What do you expect from `.AutoFilter 7, ""` filtering in column "C:C" range? Do you want filtering the whole sheet on its column "G:G"? Are the headers on the fourth row? Then, in a discontinuous range `blanks.Rows.Count` returns only the rows **of the first range area**.  From which column do you want returning in the mentioned array? From "F:F" and "G:G"? And, as stated above, `On Error Resume Next` only not let you seeing the raised errors... If you do not know how using `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData`, `On Error GoTo 0` is nec after

Comment: @FaneDuru I want to get the values from column F. The header is on row 4. So I want to return the values from column F based on if the G cell is blank or not. Could I use an if statement before the first loop i.e if cell.offset(0, 5) = “” Then, to eliminate using the with statement?

Comment: What "G cell is blank or NOT" does mean? Shouldn't the column be filtered only if **the cells in "G:G" are blank**? Anyhow, this should be not your main concern, I am afraid... Firstly, your code does not filter at all, in the way you try it, secondly `blanks.Rows.Count` does not return what you expect from it. Then, If my supposition, that all sheet should be filtered by blank cells in "G:G", you try returning from F:F, make some calculations with Data, but you do not use it and place in the array the existing value from F:F...  Please, try **better** describing what you try accomplishing...

Comment: For clarity and our understanding: you are filtering the sheet in column C, then you are checking values in column G (below header row 4 until the last row) and when you find an empty value in column G, you want the value from column F (same row) added to an array?

Comment: There is an excel spreadsheet with a range of data. The data is list of clients with their vat quarters in it. The main objective of the code is to send an email to myself to send a reminder to the client when the deadline is coming up. I have the email function working. All I need now is to pull the data from the range of data. I’ve got it to send a separate email with one client on each. What I want is to send one email with the list of clients on the one email to send. This snippet of code is to create the list of client which will then be sent out in the email.

Comment: @PeterT that is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code. If filters the used range of the active sheet, filters on the blank cells of "G:G" column, set the array dimensions using `Subtotal` and returns in array from column "F:F". There are `Date` calculations not used in the code, I do not understand where to be used...:

```
Sub NDJList()
 Dim List() As Variant, Alert As Date, Today As Date
 Dim Days As Integer, Due As Integer
 Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range, x As Long, rowsCount As Long

 If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

 'Determine the data to store:???
 Set rng = Range(Range("C4"), Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp))

 ActiveSheet.AutoFilter 7, "" 'filter the activesheet used range
 rowsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, rng) - 1 'numbers of rows in discontinuous range, except headers one
 With rng
        Set blanks = .Offset(1).Resize(rng.rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
       'Resize Array prior to loading data
       ReDim List(rowsCount - 1) 'zero based array...
    
       'Loop through each cell in range and store value in Array
        For Each Cell In blanks
            'Alert = Cell.Offset(0, 4)   '??? not used...
            'Today = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy") '??? not used...
            'Days = Alert - Today       '??? not used...
            List(x) = Cell.Offset(, 3).Value: x = x + 1
      Next Cell
 End With
 
  'Print values to Immediate Window
  For x = LBound(List) To UBound(List)
        Debug.Print List(x)
  Next x

End Sub
```

Commented the unused lines. Anyhow, `Offset(,4)` should return from the filtered column, meaning only blank cells, making the respective lines raising errors...

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: The date and alerts calculations are used further down the code. However, I will add this into the code to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Unique Strings From Filtered Column

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub GetNDJListTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Debug.Print GetNDJList(ws)
End Sub
```

Result for the data in the screenshot:

```
S
T
J
U
Z
Q
I
O
P
D
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function GetNDJList(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As String
    
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 4
    Const DATA_COLUMN As Long = 6
    Const FILTER_COLUMN As Long = 7
    Const FILTER_STRING As String = ""

    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim srg As Range, sdrg As Range, rOffset As Long, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        rOffset = FIRST_ROW - .Row
        rCount = .Rows.Count - rOffset
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(rOffset) ' has headers
        Set sdrg = srg.Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1) ' no headers
    End With
           
    srg.AutoFilter FILTER_COLUMN, FILTER_STRING
    
    Dim drg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set drg = sdrg.Columns(DATA_COLUMN).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' no filtered values
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dCell As Range, dString As String
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        dString = CStr(dCell.Value)
        If Len(dString) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.Exists(dString) Then dict(dString) = Empty ' first occ.
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' just blanks
    
    GetNDJList = Join(dict.Keys, vbLf)

End Function
```